# How to Parse Html after submitting search form that gives data from data base

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-scraping, web-crawler, jsoup

The data comes from a database, so how to parse HTML with this data, In my code, I connect to direct to my target page with cookies, then I connect to set search form, so how to parse with the result of the search. it comes from the backend. the code below contains my service connection code first, then the HTML of what the search form response gives, and finally, the html that appears in the network of the browser returning back after submitting the search form of the API post Method.

```
            Connection.Response redirectResponse = Jsoup.connect(internalConstant.getSearchResultURL())
                    .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
                    .sslSocketFactory(utilService.socketFactory())
                    .cookies(coky)
                    .method(Method.GET)
                    .execute();
             
            
            //search file
            
             String yestarday = utilService.getYesterdayDateString();
             logger.info("yestarday date: " + yestarday);
             
             Document responseDocument = redirectResponse.parse();
                         
            FormElement searchForm = (FormElement) responseDocument.select("form[id=searchDisputesForm]").first();
            checkElement("form element", searchForm);
            FormElement form = (FormElement) searchForm;
            Element searchField = form.select("input[name=DateFrom]").first();
            checkElement("date from: ", searchField);
            searchField.val(yestarday);
            Element searchField1 = form.select("input[name=DateTo]").first();
            checkElement("Date to: ", searchField1);
            searchField1.val(yestarday);

            Connection.Response searchResponse = form.submit()
                                         .cookies(coky)
                                         .sslSocketFactory(utilService.socketFactory())
                                         .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
                                         .method(Method.POST)
                                         .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
                                         .execute();
            
//and here is what gives me:

2020-10-15 11:37:38.193  INFO 3360 --- [http-nio-8095-exec-1] c.d.e.serviceImpl.UploaderTemplateImpl   : searchResponse :<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
 <head> 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"> 
  <title>404 - File or directory not found.</title> 
  <style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <div id="header">
   <h1>Server Error</h1>
  </div> 
  <div id="content"> 
   <div class="content-container">
    <fieldset> 
     <h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2> 
     <h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3> 
    </fieldset>
   </div> 
  </div>  
 </body>
</html>

//but the response in the network shows what I want:

<form action="/123Mobile/Portal/Dispute/SearchDisputes" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="searchDisputesForm" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="ClhG-V26p7Aj3vi6W8tarCwHk_enagGT4mDVv2AZsU4MHATOBTbEQHuFmylooB5qvxF29aF1-wSvZZ26ijlcZJn5p_OSshL3KeqcEbAaYg01" />                   
                   
                        <div class='col-md-12'>
                            
                            <div class='panel panel-grey equal-height-column' id=''>
                                <div class='panel-heading'>
                                     <h3 class='panel-title'>
                                          <i class='fa fa-tasks'></i> 
                                          Search criteria
                                     </h3>
                                </div>
                            <div class='panel-body'>
                                
                        <div class='form-group'> <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="DateFrom">Date From</label>
                        <div class='col-md-4 col-md-offset-0' id=''>
                         <input class="form-control datepicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Date From must be a date." id="DateFrom" name="DateFrom" placeholder="" type="text" value="2020-10-14" />
                         <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="DateFrom" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div><label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="DateTo">Date To</label>
                        <div class='col-md-4 col-md-offset-0' id=''>
                         <input class="form-control datepicker" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Date To must be a date." id="DateTo" name="DateTo" placeholder="" type="text" value="2020-10-14" />
                         <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="DateTo" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                        </div></div>        
                   <div class='col-md-12'>
                        <div class=' col-md-6'>
                        </div>          
                 
                   <button type='button' class='btn btn-success col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 ' id='ResetBtn' name='ResetBtn' onclick=''>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-refresh' aria-hidden='true'></span> Reset
                   </button>
                   <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 ' id='SearchBtn' name='SearchBtn' formaction='/123Mobile/Portal/Reports/SearchTransactionReport' onclick=''>
                    <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-search' aria-hidden='true'></span> Search
                   </button></div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                        
                    
                                    
                   
                        <div class='col-md-12'>
                            
                            <div class='panel panel-grey equal-height-column' id=''>
                                <div class='panel-heading'>
                                     <h3 class='panel-title'>
                                          <i class='fa fa-tasks'></i> 
                                          Search results
                                     </h3>
                                </div>
                            <div class='panel-body'>
                                
                          <div style='' class='table-responsive'><table class='table table-hover table-striped'><thead><tr><th style='width:15%;'>File Name</th><th style='width:10%;'>Scheme</th><th style='width:15%;'>Proccessing Date</th><th style='width:8%;'></th><th style='width:8%;'></th></tr> </thead><tbody><tr><td style='-moz-word-break: break-all; -o-word-break: break-all; word-break: break-word;-ms-word-break: break-all;overflow-wrap: break-word;word-wrap: break-word; width: 15%;' class=''>Transaction-FIBWallet-20201014</td><td style='-moz-word-break: break-all; -o-word-break: break-all; word-break: break-word;-ms-word-break: break-all;overflow-wrap: break-word;word-wrap: break-word; width: 10%;' class=''>FIBWallet</td><td style='-moz-word-break: break-all; -o-word-break: break-all; word-break: break-word;-ms-word-break: break-all;overflow-wrap: break-word;word-wrap: break-word; width: 15%;' class=''>2020-10-14</td><td style='width: 8%;' class=''><a href="/123Mobile/Portal/Reports/DownloadTransactionReport/40072">Download as Text </a></td><td style='width: 8%;' class=''><a href="/123Mobile/Portal/Reports/DownloadTransactionReport/40073">Download as Excel </a></td></tr></tbody></table></div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                        
                    
                 <div class='col-md-12'> <div class="pagination-container"><ul class="pagination"><li class="disabled PagedList-skipToFirst"><a>««</a></li><li class="disabled PagedList-skipToPrevious"><a rel="prev">«</a></li><li class="active"><a>1</a></li><li class="disabled PagedList-skipToNext"><a rel="next">»</a></li><li class="disabled PagedList-skipToLast"><a>»»</a></li></ul></div></div>
                 </form>
```

Comment: So, what is the problem? You are parsing using Jsoup and what is happening? Could you please elaborate on your question a bit more?

Comment: I added them, check out the code again and description above

Comment: Your response is a 404. I’m not sure parsing it is going to be useful.

Comment: `"form[id='searchDisputesForm']"` with apostrophes?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need to get a session cookie and some other info from the server with headers, I'd avoid starting with a GET request and go straight for the POST form request.

You say the response you're getting looks something like

```html
<h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>
```

which suggests you're making the POST request without the correct headers sent across OR the page is a single page app that makes some subsequent (asynchronous) request which then modifies the page source.

I can't really help much further with the info provided, other than to say look at using Chrome dev tools on the network tab to investigate what requests are being sent to the server when the POST request happens. Look at the headers.

Typical headers of interest involve some sort of session cookie, possibly a referrer header. But if those two alone don't get you what you want you'll need to start replicating the request exactly... There may be CSRF tokens in the form you need to obtain (in which case the initial GET request is essential to obtain a valid token to send back in the POST).

Comment: your right it was the session id and the request vervication token, the input field of the search form.